# Copying Private chain data to another private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, chaindata

I have two independent private chains running with unique genesis file each. If we use same accounts in both the chains is there a way to copy the state or data of chain 1 to chain 2.

Regards,
Manoj

Comment: Is chain 2 already running? Are you looking to merge 2 chains, or do you want to restore the existing state of chain 1 into a new chain? If it's the latter, you can take a snapshot of your chaindata and use it as the genesis for your new chain.

Comment: Chain 2 is not yet started, it need to be started. But it will be started with a different genesis file from that of chain 1. I am not looking to merge the 2 chains, I want to take the data of chain 1 and continue chain 2 as a new separate chain.

Comment: actually I also looking something similar in a way that once I take bakeup of blocks then when I restart the node I can use backup and node will start syncing from where backup has left any idea?

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to do a backup & restore. I've been looking into this, to update our genesis configuration for a private Parity chain, but never go to actually try it.

As far as I know there's no clean way to do this, without exporting state `parity export state`, see [Parity docs](https://openethereum.github.io/wiki/CLI-Sub-commands#export-state). This command requires the chain to be synced with –fat-db on. You can use the JSON output in the accounts section of your new chain. Rename state to accounts and remove the keys that the node complains about (code_hash and storage_root - these are calculated at runtime). All nodes that are using that genesis need to import `parity import` before syncing with the network, or use `warp-sync`.

I received this previously from Parity's support. See https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum/issues/10304

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am using geth, any pointers for geth

Comment: I don't have any experience with Geth, but checking their docs, it seems they have similar export/import functionality to RLP. I guess it works the same that you could use that for your genesis config. https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options

Answer (score 0):

To merge states of two private blockchains

- Assuming there is no overlap on accounts and assets between two chains
- Create and fund genesis accounts of chain #1 on chain #2
- Replay all transactions of chain #1 on chain #2

Comment: Thanks for the response, this means you say to re-transact all transactions of chain1 on chain2?

Comment: I think that's the easiest solution assuming states cannot conflict.

Comment: okay, is there any way we can copy states and blocks of chain1 to chain2?